# i18next special features when using RequireJS-i18next-plugin

Tags: javascript, requirejs, i18next

I'm using i18next to handle translations on a project.
It comes with a lot of nice features, like those two:

```
// pluralization (http://i18next.com/translate/pluralSimple/):
i18next.t('apple', {count: 5}); // apples

// translation context (http://i18next.com/translate/context/):
i18next.t('friend', {context: 'male'}); // A boyfriend
```

Howerver, my project also uses RequireJS, and its i18next plugin, which, as mentionned into the documentation (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#i18n), works like so:

I declare the translations into a RequireJS module :

```
//Contents of my/nls/translations.js
define({
    "root": {
        "friend": "A friend",
        "friend_male": "A boyfriend",
        "friend_female": "A girlfriend",

        "apple": "apple",
        "apple_plural": "apples"
    },
    "fr-fr": {
        "friend": "Un ami",
        "friend_male": "Un petit ami",
        "friend_female": "Un petite amie",

        "apple": "pomme",
        "apple_plural": "pommes"
    }
});
```

And then I load and use them that way:

```
//Content of my/logic.js
var translations = require("i18n!my/nls/translations.js");
console.log(translations.friend); // logs "Un ami" (in my French browser!)
```

However, I such context, I don't understand how I can use the various features of i18next that I mentioned above (pluralization, context, and so on). This doesn't appear into the plugin's documentation. I'm a bit lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RequireJS i18n plugin does not work with i18next. Use [require-i18next](https://github.com/jcbvm/require-i18next) plugin

**RequireJS i18n** plugin is a simple `key=>val` mapper. **i18next** is a powerful tool.

I personally don't use a require-i18next plugin. I use domready plugin and this code:

```
domReady(function () {
  i18n.init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    shortcutFunction: 'sprintf',
    nsseparator: ':::',
    keyseparator: '::'
  }, initApp);
});
```

where `initApp` is function that runs my app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I'm a bit surprised, though, of what you say about the official plugin. What do you mean by "does not work"? As for the last piece of code I gave above, it works fine for me. Do you mean that I won't be able to use the other features? I'm also wondering about Require Optimization: do you mean it won't work?

As for jcbvm/require-i18next, I'm trying to install it, but I'am facing some issues. I might come again for another question about that.